# I am unable to trace the error in the following code

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-1) coordinate (x); \draw (0,1) coordinate (y); \draw[fill]
(x) circle (1.5pt) node[below]{\small $x$}; \draw[fill] (y) circle
(1.5pt) node[above]{\small $y$};
\draw [thick,->] (x) .. controls +(180:1cm) and +(0,0) .. (-1,0) 
node[end,left] {$a$};
\draw [thick] (y) .. controls +(180:1cm) and +(0,0) .. (-1,0);
\draw [thick,->] (x) .. controls +(0:1cm) and +(0,0) .. (1,0) 
node[end,right] {$d$};;
\draw [thick] (y) .. controls +(0:1cm) and +(0,0) .. (1,0);
\draw [thick,->] (x) .. controls +(180:.4cm) and +(0,0) .. (-.4,0) 
node[end,left] {$b$};
\draw [thick] (y) .. controls +(180:.4cm) and +(0,0) .. (-.4,0);
\draw [thick,->] (x) .. controls +(0:.4cm) and +(0,0) .. (.4,0) 
node[end,right] {$c$};
\draw [thick] (y) .. controls +(0:.4cm) and +(0,0) .. (.4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `node[near end...` instead of `node[end...`

Comment: I don't know which editor you're using and how it displays errors, but the complete error message is quite clear, I think. First it says `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/end' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` Then later it says `l.14 node[end,left] {$a$};` (14 is a line number, so will likely be different for you). So it tells you which line the problem is in, and that the key `end` is the problem.

Comment: If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) by clicking on the arrows next to the score. If any of the answers solve your problem then mark the best solution as an [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) by clicking on the checkmark ✓.

Answer (score 7):

cause of error can be solved with [CarLaTeX's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex) comment or by `node[at end,...]`. however (off-topic) your image can be drawn on the following slightly shorter way:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
DL/.style = {% Decorated Line
             decoration={markings, mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Straight Barb}},},
             postaction={decorate},
             },
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, inner sep=2pt, font=\scriptsize}
                    ]
\node (a) [dot] at (0,-1) {};
\node (b) [dot] at (0,+1) {};
\draw[DL] (a) to [out=150, in=210,"a"] (b);
\draw[DL] (a) to [out=105, in=255,"b"] (b);
\draw[DL] (a) to [out= 75, in=285,"c" '] (b);
\draw[DL] (a) to [out= 30, in=330,"d" '] (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 When I need arrows like this I define your `DL` style as `->-/.style={...}`. This way it looks like an arrow as it is used as `\draw[->-](a) to (b);` etc. Of course, it's equivalent to what you have (except that `DL` is one character shorter...).

Comment: @Andrew, your way seems to be more meaningful than DL, which should remind on "Decorate Line"  :-)